# How to test an add to list method with JUnit

Tags: eclipse, maven, testing, junit

I'm trying to test my add to list method using JUnit.

Here is my test method:

```
public int urunEkleTest(String marka, String urun) {
        UrunDepo depo = new UrunDepo();
        
        String urunekle = depo.urunEkle("Iphone","Apple");
```

But I have a error message with this test method

Error msg = The method urunEkle(Urun) in the type UrunDepo is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

And my add to list method is :

```
public static List<Urun> urunEkle(Urun urun){
            URUNLER.add(urun);
            return URUNLER;
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You call a method with one parameter with two parameters.

Comment: I changed to two parameters but im getting the same error

Comment: Type Urun is not Type String.

Comment: I changed it to Urun too

Comment: UrunDepo depo = depo.urunEkle("Iphone","Apple");

Comment: I think you need to learn basic Java first.